# The boundary of a chain of plane squares

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, plane-curves

Denote by $\mathbb{Z}$ the set of whole numbers, by $\mathbb{R}$ the set of real numbers, and by $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ the set extended real numbers $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$. We denote intervals of extended real numbers as usual by $[a,b]$, $[a,b)$, $(a,b]$, and $(a,b)$. Define $\mathbb{N}_1 = \mathbb{Z}\cap[1,\infty)$, so that $\mathbb{N}_1 = \{1,2,\dots\}$,

Denote by $\mathbf{S}$ the set consisting of all the subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $[a,a+1]\times[b,b+1]$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. The members of $\mathbf{S}$ shall be referred to as *squares*. A *chain* in $\mathbf{T} \subseteq \mathbf{S}$ is a non-empty, finite sequence $S_1, S_2, \dots, S_n \in \mathbf{T}$, such that for every $k \in \{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$, $S_k$ and $S_{k+1}$ have at least one side in common. $A, B \in \mathbf{S}$ are said to be *$\mathbf{T}$-connected* iff there is a chain $S_1, S_2, \dots, S_n$ in $\mathbf{T}$ with $S_1 = A$, and $S_n = B$. It can be verified that the relation of $\mathbf{T}$-connectedness is an equivalence relation on $\mathbf{T}$. The corresponding equivalence classes shall be called the *components of $\mathbf{T}$*. $\mathbf{T}$ is said to be *connected* iff it has a single component.

If $T$ is a subset of the Euclidean plane, denote by $\overline{T}$ the topological closure of $T$. If $P$ is a Jordan curve in the Euclidean plane, denote by $i(P)$ the interior of $P$, and by $e(P)$ the exterior of $P$.

Let $\mathbf{T}$ be a non-empty, finite, connected subset of $\mathbf{S}$, and define $T = \cup\mathbf{T}$. I wish to show that $T$'s boundary can be represented as the union of $k \in \mathbb{N}_1$ closed, simple polygonal curves $P_1, \dots, P_k$, such that $T$ is contained in $\overline{i(P_1)}$, and for every $i \in \{2, \dots, k\}$, $T$ is contained in $\overline{e(P_i)}$.

It is easy to convince oneself of the validity of this claim when $\mathbf{T}$ consists of a single square. However, the general case eludes me.

---

**Source**

The claim I wish to prove is a major step in the proof of Theorem 4.14 "A bounded domain $G$ is simply connected if and only if whenever $G$ contains a closed Jordan curbve $\gamma$, $G$ also contains $I(\gamma)$" on pp. 70-72 of A. I. Markushevich's *Theory of Functions of a Complex Variable, Three volumes in one*, 2nd Edition, Chelsea Publishing Company, 1977.

Comment: This method is used in Christenson/Voxman 'Aspects of Topology,' so the proof should be there.  For us to be able to answer this questions without having a copy of your book, we would have to know what you do/don't already have at your disposal from plane topology and complex analysis.  Because different books order (or omit) things differently.  Like, do you not already have the Jordan Curve Theorem?  You mention interior and exterior.  But, this characterization you're looking for is usually used to prove the JCT in the first place.

Comment: @JohnSamples: The Jordan Curve Theorem is available at the time the above claim is made. (It has been stated without proof.)